# PHP problem, I'm sure this has an easy solution, just can't see it

Tags: php, xml, string

I am new to php and this little bugger has been eating up my day, perhaps it's due to some property of php I am unaware of?

As part of some code for getting some data out of an xml file (using the event based Expat parser), I have the following code

```
$xmlFields;
$fieldName = "";
```

............... some other code ............

```
function char($parser,$data)
{

    global $xmlFields, $fieldName;

    if($fieldName) {
        if($fieldName == "brandName" || "oeNumber" || "articleId" || "quantityPerPackingUnit" || "attrName") {
             $xmlFields[$fieldName] = $data;
             echo $data;
        } 
    }
}
```

I try to echo `$xmlFields["brandName"]` for example, and nothing is printed.

1) I know that `$xmlFields["brandName"]` is non-empty because echo $data actually returns something.

2) If I change to `$xmlFields[$fieldName] = 'some string';`
then `echo $xmlFields["brandName"]` will print 'some string'

so why won't it print `$xmlFields["brandName"]`?

Thanks in advance,
Yazan

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The following expression

```
$fieldName == "brandName" || "oeNumber" || "articleId" || "quantityPerPackingUnit" || "attrName"
```

is parsed as

```
(
  (
    (
      ($fieldName == "brandName") || ("oeNumber")
    ) || ("articleId")
  ) || ("quantityPerPackingUnit")
) || ("attrName")
```

Notice that your equality check is separated from the other checks.  In this case, the expression always evaluates to `true`.

You can use an array for this case:

```
in_array($fieldName, array("brandName", "oeNumber", "articleId", "quantityPerPackingUnit", "attrName"));
```

Comment: Thank you all, you're comments were very helpful. Problem solved.

Answer (score 7):

You cannot link ORs like that.
try

```
    if($fieldName == "brandName" || $fieldName =="oeNumber" || $fieldName =="articleId" || $fieldName =="quantityPerPackingUnit" || $fieldName == "attrName") {
```

As Deceze said a much better option when you are searching in an array is to use

```
if (in_array($fieldName, array("brandName", "oeNumber", "articleId", "quantityPerPackingUnit", "attrName")))
```

I know some languages allow such construct but php is not one of them.

Answer (score 3):

Try this as a shorter version of Iznogood's answer:

```
if (in_array($fieldName, array("brandName", "oeNumber", "articleId", "quantityPerPackingUnit", "attrName")))
```